# Problem getting value from deserialized file if doesn't exists

Tags: c#, serialization, deserialization

I'm currently trying to set a "firstRun" boolean to run a piece of code only when the app is started for the first time.

GameData.cs

```
[System.Serializable]
 public class GameData
 {
     
     public static string saveFileName = "Pixel.pixel";
 
     public double money;
     public bool firstRun;
 
     public GameData()
     {
         money = GameController.Instance.CurrentCash;
     }
 }
```

SaveSystem.cs

```
 using System.IO;
 using System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary;
 
 public static class SaveSystem
 {
 
     public static void SaveData()
     {
         BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
 
         string path = Application.persistentDataPath + "/" + GameData.saveFileName;
         FileStream stream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create);
 
         GameData data = new GameData();
         formatter.Serialize(stream, data);
 
         stream.Close();
     }
 
     public static GameData LoadData()
     {
         string path = Application.persistentDataPath + "/" + GameData.saveFileName;
         if (File.Exists(path))
         {
             BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
             
             FileStream stream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open);
 
             GameData data = formatter.Deserialize(stream) as GameData;
             
             stream.Close();
 
             return data;
         }
         else
         {
             return null;
         }
     }
 }
```

GameController.cs part

```
 public void Start()
     {
         Setup(START_CASH);
         /*AddCash(START_CASH);*/
     }
 
     private void Setup(double value)
     {
         GameData data = SaveSystem.LoadData();
         if (!data.firstRun)
         {
             CurrentCash += value;
             SaveSystem.SaveData();
         }
         else
         {
             CurrentCash = data.money;
             SaveSystem.SaveData();
         }
         UI.CashDisplay.text = ShortScaleString.parseDouble(CurrentCash, 1, 1000, scientificFormat);
     }
```

My problem is that I need to check if "data.firstRun" is false/doesn't exist to run a setup part but I literally don't know how to achieve this

Answer (score 0):

You should just return a new 'GameData', with your prefered value (true or false):

```
public static GameData LoadData()
{
    string path = Application.persistentDataPath + "/" + GameData.saveFileName;
    if (File.Exists(path))
    {
        BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();

        FileStream stream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open);

        GameData data = formatter.Deserialize(stream) as GameData;

        stream.Close();

        return data;
    }
    else
    {
        return new GameData { firstRun = true };
    }
}
```

Comment: I didn't specify it but the "money" and "firstRun" are only 2 of all the variables I need to store. I will try it but I need firstRun to return false instead of true and then store it as true and save it. Thanks for your reply, I will try it

Comment: Your LoadData method was returning null if it didn't find the file, so I think you should implement a generic return, like New GameData { firtsRun default value; money default value} . There is a posibility, that the file gets deleted and you have to handle that to.